# Using MongoDB aggregation to count occurrences between two arrays

Tags: mongodb, express

I have a collection like that:

```
[
  {
    "query": {
      "filters": {
        "cities": [
          "Warsaw"
        ],
        "universities": [],
        "fieldOfStudyTypes": [],
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "query": {
      "filters": {
        "cities": [
          "Miami"
        ],
        "universities": [],
        "fieldOfStudyTypes": [],
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "query": {
      "filters": {
        "cities": [
          "Warsaw",
          "New York"
        ],
        "universities": [],
        "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
          "Computer Science",
          "History"
        ],
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "query": {
      "filters": {
        "cities": [
          "London"
        ],
        "universities": [],
        "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
          "Computer Science"
        ],
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "query": {
      "filters": {
        "cities": [
          "Paris"
        ],
        "universities": [],
        "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
          "Computer Science"
        ],
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "query": {
      "filters": {
        "cities": [
          "Paris"
        ],
        "universities": [],
        "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
          "Computer Science"
        ],
        
      },
      
    }
  }
]
```

Using `aggregate`, I would like to know:

- how many times a certain city, or university, or fieldOfStudyType occurs
- how many times a certain fieldOfStudyType occurs with a certain city

The first task seems to be fairly straightforward. For example, to count all occurrences of certain cities, I can do the following:

```
{
  $unwind: '$query.filters.cities',
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$query.filters.cities',
     total: { $sum: 1 },
  },
},
```

This produces an output as this one:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "London",
    "total": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "Miami",
    "total": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "Paris",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "New York",
    "total": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "Warsaw",
    "total": 2
  }
]
```

I can't seem to figure out how to count fieldOfStudyType occurrences with a certain city. I would like to have something like that:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "London",
    "total": 1,
    "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
      {
        "_id": "Computer Science",
        "total": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Miami",
    "total": 1,
    "fieldOfStudyTypes": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "Paris",
    "total": 2,
    "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
      {
        "_id": "Computer Science",
        "total": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "New York",
    "total": 1,
    "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
      {
        "_id": "Computer Science",
        "total": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "History",
        "total": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Warsaw",
    "total": 2,
    "fieldOfStudyTypes": [
      {
        "_id": "Computer Science",
        "total": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "History",
        "total": 1
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/fspiZ52UTKd helps you? I feel the given data set is correct one, please double check and breif more

Comment: @varman It appears like we are going somewhere, but it does not look exactly right. The "fieldOfStudyTypes" array seems to always have one element.
Here is a bigger example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kww0z3GBg3V

Comment: @varman Also with your query, the city is not counted if it does not have any fieldOfStudyTypes, which is not the goal, unfortunately. The fieldOfStudyType should be an empty array then

Comment: I dont understand your "5ea0934ad46cd10d5a778320" is in two cities, but field of types in your expected answer total =1

Comment: @varman You are right, I just changed the data. I hope it is clearer now

Comment: is this https://mongoplayground.net/p/j8gRTKo-0rj what you expected?

Comment: I need to know, what if cities and universities have some value?

Comment: @varman Unfortunately, in your example it counts "5ea092fdd46cd10d5a77831c" twice instead of once - "total" for this city should be 1. We can also notice that the cities with no fieldOfStudyTypes are not counted at all.

Comment: The problem I faced is the objectId :'(. If you entered as simple id for example like Sting or integer, we can easily debug it. will see

Comment: @varman A good point
https://mongoplayground.net/p/fgWW_UBiSFe

Comment: If you never mind, can you edit back your question as you posted above? and your expected output

Comment: @varman Sure, I just did that

Comment: thank you, i will look into this and let you know

Comment: I wonder, https://mongoplayground.net/p/naZ-mXjPFeV this is the expected output

Comment: @varman We are still missing "Miami" with no fieldOfStudyTypes. Also, "Computer Science" for Paris should have a total of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the expected output from the below query. If you need to do the steps fr universities also, you just follow the steps what I have done for cities

```
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$query.filters.cities",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$query.filters.cities",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      fieldOfStudyTypes: {
        $addToSet: "$query.filters.fieldOfStudyTypes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      fieldOfStudyTypes: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$fieldOfStudyTypes",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$fieldOfStudyTypes",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      fieldOfStudyTypes: {
        $addToSet: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $gt: [
                "$fieldOfStudyTypes",
                null
              ]
            },
            {
              id: "$fieldOfStudyTypes",
              total: {
                $sum: 1
              }
            },
            {}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      fieldOfStudyTypes: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$fieldOfStudyTypes",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this",
              {}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Monog playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z2ERuIxMRER)

Comment: The total value for Computer Science in Paris should be 2, not 1.

Comment: Its 2 not 1. I gave you the example also

Comment: I tested it in the Mongo Playground you provided and the "Computer Science" has a total of 1 for "Paris".

Comment: As you given in the expected result

Comment: I see. I'm sorry for this mixup. Since "Computer Science" appears twice for Paris, its total should be 2

Comment: I think I got it to work by modifying your example https://mongoplayground.net/p/L4pBmye1xYj

Comment: It did help a lot. Thank you very much